# css to remove/hide html tag from html body

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<div style="display: none;" id="hideme"><input id="test" name="test" value="test" type="hidden"> </div>
```

and i am applying css display:none but still it is displayed in html body. i want to hide that div from body html.

Comment: It's not displaying, so it's working

Comment: It can't, it won't be visible in your browser if you're applying `display: none`

Comment: CSS can't "hide" html from being served to the client. It only specifies how it should be displayed by the browser (stylesheet!).

Answer (score 0):

try to move `display:none;` to the last attribute after `id="hideme"` , i'm not sure if your #hideme has something like `display:block`.
or you can give us your full html page.

Answer (score 0):

You try use:

```
display: none !important;
```

Comment: This looks like an answer to me (although it's not a very detailed answer). You might be able to improve it with a more detailed explanation.